# Google Script stringdate format to date format

Tags: google-apps-script

I get data from external system it gives me date format like this "okt 21, 2017". With google script i want to change it to "2017-10-21"

I have traid this but i get the right results.

```
Var test = "okt 21, 2017";
     range.setValue(new Date(test.getYear(),test.getMonth(),test.getDay()));
      //range.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(test, "GMT" , "yyyy-MM-dd"));

          //range.setValue(date(value).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
          //range.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Output what i get is :  1970-01-01

Solution, not a great one but it works

```
 switch (sheetName) { 
case "sheetnameeeee": 
      range.setValue(dateChange(value)).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 break; 
} 

function dateChange(value) { 
var dateString = value; 
dateString = dateString.toString().replace("maa", "mar"); 
dateString = dateString.toString().replace("mei", "may"); 
dateString = dateString.toString().replace("okt", "oct"); 
return dateString;}
```

Comment: I traid that but nothing happend. No data is change. Language is VS in the spreadsheet.. the data is German

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution:

- Set Spreadsheet Locale to `German`
- `setValue(date string)` directly.

#### Code snippet:

```
var test = "okt 21, 2017"; //Recognized date format in German-Google-Sheets
range.setValue(test).setNumberFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: `I can not change the language it need to stay in VS` why?

Comment: Because other script and query's that are running on it.. Plus policy in the Company..

Comment: @FT If it's worth anything, You only need to change `locale`- No need to change language.